# Hide Intent if Default Data Inserted

Tags: android, android-intent

I have an intent that appear only if certain data have not been inserted yet. It's like a custom form  to insert some data. If the data have been inserted, in the future the apps opened, the intent will not appear anymore. It will open another intent, the default one. (Usually this might occur when the apps opened for the first time)

How do I manage the intent since the default intent could only be one?

For example: If the apps opened for the first time it will startIntent Form
             next time the apps opened (assumed the data already inserted) it will startIntent MainActivity

Comment: Use shared preferences and store a value indicating weather the app has already been called up or if it is the first run.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i use sharedpreferences to insert data only once , simply use it this way, in the below code 
 the intent will be started only once the application is first installed, after that it will start the   main activity intent.

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

if (isFirstTime()) {
// startIntent Form
}

}



private boolean isFirstTime()
{
SharedPreferences preferences = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
boolean ranBefore = preferences.getBoolean("RanBefore", false);
if (!ranBefore) {
// first time
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("RanBefore", true);
editor.commit();
}
return !ranBefore;
}
```

Comment: Well I think I'm gonna use this alternative. But do you know how to do  it if I want the data be inserted every month (once a month) not just only once as shown above?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are doing something like registration thing, and want to show this form once. you have many options here.

1) As Ahmad(in the comments) says use [SharedPreferences](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html), and add some flag into it, which can tell you if the data is available or not. add a check in the very beginning of the activity/onCreate and open respective inten/activity depends on check.

2) you can use Database as well to see this value.

I would suggest you to use SPLASH screen, check this value/registration data into it. And if available start Activity A, else start Registration/default one.

Comment: I currently choose the second one and it has some errors. Here's what I do to the code, I check the particular row in a table if it's null it will do the intent (let say intent A) but if it's not null it will do the other intent (intent B). The problem is, in the manifest I choose intent B as a default one (After the splash screen). It can't have 2 intents as default can't it?

Comment: your default intent would be SPLASH SCREEN/Activity(make it Main). From here either you ll go to Screen A or Screen B depending on your situation.